# Would you allow this Spotify question here?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm curious whether you think this might be an appropriate question to ask on Web Apps:

[What artists are not available on Spotify?](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/2543/what-artists-are-not-available-on-spotify)

I asked it at Music Fans, where it was closed for well-meaning, but I think misguided reasons. You can read those reasons in the comments at the OP, and also in this extended Meta discussion:

https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256/should-we-re-open-the-spotify-blacklist-question

This is a question that I will personally receive great value from, and I think it will provide significant value to the internet as a whole. Stack Exchange is uniquely positioned to host a question like this. Our platform wasn't built for list questions, but it works for them, and there are numerous exceptions across the network where it's been demonstrated they can thrive. I think this might be one of those exceptions, but there's only one way to find out.

I'd be grateful if you gave the question a chance, but also I understand it might not be welcome here either. I'm willing to moderate it myself (since as OP I'd receive inbox notifications). If you feel the risk of spam is too great, we can "protect" the question, though I'd rather give it a chance to live in the wild and see how big a problem spam really is.

Looking forward to your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, avoiding the risk of everything that was repeated at that meta, *the answer is no.*

(with the supporting really good reasons already stated by Gilles et al.)

This might sound harsh, but this is a discussion that has last probably 3 or more years across Stack Exchange. I'm surprised you didn't talk to the rest of the Stack Overflow employees about experiences when it comes this.

If this is something you want to see discussed in length, the appropriate place will be meta.stackexchange.com since this applies to all SE sites. Or even in the Teacher's Lounge

<sub>(I'd join the chat based on what alcohol I have in the cupboard since I really am tired of this topic, and it will allow me to be more relaxed and open about discussing it one last time)</sub>

Given our stance on many other questions closed on this site with similar scenarios, I do not expect any moderator here to allow this question to happen. You will need the community team to step in and give better options to ones you have supplied.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. This disappoints me, but makes plenty of sense. Lemme know if the tide ever changes and you think a question like this would ever be allowed.